# Turn a Block into a Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, scope, associations

I have a block in a view:

```
<% current_user.friends.each do |friend| %>
  <% friend.courses.each do |course| %>
    <%= course.course_name%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and I was reading through the Rails Guides and [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) because it seemed to me that this was the sort of thing that I could bring into a model via a scope. I have two questions:

1. Is this the sort of thing I can bring into the model via a scope?
2. How would I go about doing that?

The relationships are as follows:

```
class User
  has_many :friends, through: friendships
  has_many :friendships, conditions: "status = 'accepted'"
  has_many :courses

class Course
  belongs_to :user
```

I have tried a few different variations of scope, particularly in the Course model. The one I tried most recently was:

```
scope :friend_courses, joins(:user => :friends)
```

but that didn't return courses belonging to a user's friends.

The code I have in the block works, so if I have to use that, I will. But it seems like there's a way to user eager loading here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friend_courses, :through => :friends, :source => :courses
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :friendships, :conditions => {:status => 'accepted'}
  has_many :courses
end

user.friend_courses
```